# ¿Cómo hacer un insert en sql desde c#?

Tags: c#, tsql

Estoy intentando insertar un dato en en SQL Server 2012 desde C# pero no puedo porque me tira un error en la clave foránea pero la otra tabla la tengo con datos.
¿Me podrian ayudar?

[image: Se detectó SqlException]

Comment: El error es claramente por falta de una FK, espera un valor de la tabla Localidad la cual me imagino tiene el valor `Dueño_Localidad` el valor tiene que ser IGUAL al valor insertado en la otra tabla.

Comment: Hola user47426, bienvenido a [es.so], aquí te van algunas recomendaciones. 1.- No pongas imágenes, copia y pega el código. 2.- Pon el código completo, es decir, lo que llevas en la sentencia SQL y estructura de tablas. Con eso será más fácil ayudarte y determinar dónde se encuentra la falla :D

Comment: Lo mas probable es  ids ingresado en la tabla localidad este corridos.  Copia los valores en un excel y realizar un truncate tabla localidad para que los id comiencen desde el inicio.Luego copia los valores del excel a la tabla.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que validar el valor que asignas al campo relacionado con la otra tabla ya que esta claro que no se encuentra.

O sea si en la tabla de localidades tienes imaginemos 3 registros con las localidades id 1, 2 y 3 entonces cuando defines el insert en el campo de dueños debes asignar en ese campos de localidad uno de estas localidades exisstentes, si definieras un valor 4 en este campos de la tabla dueño tendrias exactamente ese mensaje de error

Cuando falle pasa el mouse por sobre la variable `sSql` y evalua los valores que asignas a los campos, poniendo foco en la localidad.

Adicionalmente veo que envias solo un string para la ejecucion del sql, lo cual me hace pensar que concatenas los valores en lugar de utilizar parametros. Recomendaria hacer uso de algo como ser

```
public int ExecuteNonQuery(string sSql, List<SqlParameter> pList)
{
    open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSql, mConeccion);

    foreach(var p in pList)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
    }

    int rowAfected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    return rowAfected;
}
```

Entonces lo usarias

```
string sSql = "INSERT INTO Dueño (campo1, campo2, LocalidadId) VALUES (@param1, @param2, @localidad)";

List<SqlParameter> pList = new List<SqlParameter>();

SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParamter("@param1", TextBox1.Text);
pList.Add(p1);

SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParamter("@param2", TextBox2.Text);
pList.Add(p2);

SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParamter("@localidad", Convert.ToInt32(cmdLocalidades.SelectedValue));
pList.Add(p3);

int rowAfected = ExecuteNonQuery(sSql, pList);
```

de esta forma estarias definiendo correctamente los valores de cada campo del insertusando parametros y no concatenando en el string.

Recuerda que el ExecuteNonQuery() del SqlCommand retorna las filas afectadas, no es un id como veo defines en la variable.